# Keep the height/width of UITextField the same on iPad and iPhone with AutoLayout

Tags: ios, autolayout

This is my first StackOverflow post. I had a question about Auto Layouts in Xcode. I've started to get the hang of this system and so far it is working pretty well. The only problem I am trying to solve is related to my text fields. Currently, my auto layout constraints are set that the the textfield gets stretched out iPad. My ideal layout is to have the textfields be the same size as they are on iPhone and still centered on the iPad display... Please see accompanying screen shots for reference. I've tried many Interface Builder Constraint combination, but I cannot figure out the correct one? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

[Current Auto Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EABr6.png)

[Intended Auto Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2K0b.png)

Answer (score 2):

1- Remove the leading and trailing constraints attached to the email & password textfields & the button

2- Control-drag from the email textfield to the superview and select ( with <kbd>shift</kbd> key pressed ) both **Equal-Widths & centerX**

3- Click the **Equal-Width** constraint and change it's *multiplier* to say 0.5 to occupy half screen in any device

4- To avoid repeating for the password textfield and the button Control-drag from each one to the email textfield and select **Equal-Widths & centerX** plus top constraint to the item above each one

**Note :** If you find that 0.5 multiplier is suitable for Ipad and not for Iphone you can create 2 different widths for them with size classes

> width:0.8 -----> installed for All except wRhR (Ipad)
>
> width:0.5 -----> installed for only wRhR